# Router firmware update failing

Tags: router, firmware

I am trying to update the firmware of a Tenda router model F3 via my phone by wirelessly connecting it to the router. I am accessing it's interface using it's gateway IP and putting it on the web browser. The router does not have an internet connection and I'm trying to update it's firmware locally. It says that the current firmware version is "V03.03.01.33_multi"

I've downloaded the firmware software from https://www.tendacn.com/br/product/download/f3.html. The correct firmware version depends on the hardware version of the router. Internet says that this information should be displayed on the back of the device. Here's a look (translated from Chinese using an app):

[image]

At the end of the listed number, it says version 8.0 and there is no such version on the site. So I tested pretty much all of them. Version 3.0 simply said "error to update firmware, rebooting the router", which I assume is because of incompatibility. Versions 4.0 and 1.0 did work apparently but instead displayed the message "firmware file is too large". What should I do? If I committed some mistake at any point please correct me.

Comment: v4.0 Firmware is the most likely to be the match (given that it runs on the same firmware version range as your currently installed firmware).

Comment: Can you try a wired connection from a PC to the router? And also, try a factory reset of the router before trying the upgrade.

Comment: I tried the wired connection using every version, making sure to use the .bin files. The same error messages appeared in each version in the same manner as before. Version 3 simply failed and versions 1 and 4 it said that the file is too large.